# searching different value in one column

Tags: sql, database

i have a transaction table like this

```
cust_id | item
---------------------
1       | book
1       | shoe
2       | book
3       | shoe
```

how can i use SQL command to find customer who bought book and shoe together?
so, the result can be only customer 1.
I need to do Apriori project, iv try to google, but i dunno the correct phrase to be googled, please help me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT cust_id FROM table WHERE item='book'
INTERSECT 
SELECT cust_id FROM table WHERE item='shoe'
```

*http://ideone.com/V74E4*

Answer (score 3):

You can use a self-join:

```
select a.cust_id
from transaction a, transactions b
where a.cust_id = b.cust_id
  and a.item = 'book'
  and b.item = 'shoe'
```

The use of two references to the `transactions` table creates a cartesian product (every row combined with every row) of all `book` and `shoe` buyers which will, when limited by the `a.cust_id = b.cust_id` clause, exclude all those that only bought one of them, as below, where only customer 1 satisfies *all* the requirements (`X 'book' X 'shoe'`, where `X` is any customer ID, but the same in both columns 1 and 3 of the result set):

```
a.cust_id | a.item | b.cust_id | b.item | include?
----------+--------+-----------+--------+---------
    1     | book   |    1      | book   |
    1     | shoe   |    1      | book   |
    2     | book   |    1      | book   |
    3     | shoe   |    1      | book   |

    1     | book   |    1      | shoe   |   yes
    1     | shoe   |    1      | shoe   |
    2     | book   |    1      | shoe   |
    3     | shoe   |    1      | shoe   |

    1     | book   |    2      | book   |
    1     | shoe   |    2      | book   |
    2     | book   |    2      | book   |
    3     | shoe   |    2      | book   |

    1     | book   |    3      | shoe   |
    1     | shoe   |    3      | shoe   |
    2     | book   |    3      | shoe   |
    3     | shoe   |    3      | shoe   |
```

There's probably a way to do this with an explicit `join` statement as well but, since I use a DBMS that's smart enough to figure it out, I don't care. I won't state *which* DBMS since I don't want to start a religious war :-)